# Прокрутка страницы по горизонтали зажатой левой клавишей мыши

Tags: jquery, javascript

Задача:
Есть длинная страница по горизонтали более 3000px. Необходимо скролить страницу просто хватая левой кнопкой мыши за любую точку страницы, и тянув её, аналог обычного виндовского просмотрщика изображений.

Вот что я навоял (все работает, но не гладко, в некоторых моментах страница дергается, и нижний скрол теперь нельзя тягать отдельно), тут показываю только JS, и [вот txt файл](http://javascript.ru/forum/attachments/events/1957d1381790544-scroll-po-telu-stranicy-s-pomoshhyu-myshi-tmp-txt) полностью функциональной страницы:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEUP|Event.MOUSEDOWN);

    document.onmousedown=DRAG_begindrag;
    document.onmouseup=DRAG_enddrag;

    var DRAG_lastX, DRAG_dragging;
    function DRAG_begindrag(e) {
        if (e.which == 1) {
            window.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
            window.onmousemove=DRAG_drag;

            DRAG_lastX=e.pageX;
            DRAG_dragging=true;
            return false;
        }
        else {return true;}
    }
    function DRAG_enddrag(e) {
        if (e.which == 1) {
            window.releaseEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);

            window.onmousemove=null
            DRAG_dragging=false;
            return false;
        }
        else {return true;}
    }
    function DRAG_drag(e) {
        if (DRAG_dragging) {
            s1 = e.pageX - DRAG_lastX
            s = window.pageXOffset - s1;
            window.scroll(s);
            DRAG_lastX = e.pageX;
            return false;
        }
        else {return true;}
    }
});
</script>
```

Помогите пожалуйста понять, почему страница дергается, и как отвязаться от нижнего скрола, чтобы он отдельно хорошо работал.

Comment: сделайте jsfiddle, ваш txt  файл требует авторизации.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

в вашем коде разбираться не хотелось, вот такое например сделал:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $doc = $(document),
        ratio = $doc.width() / $(window).width(), //отношение окна к общей ширене блока, чтобы тянуть весь блок.
        mousepos, to;
    $doc.on('mousedown', '#content', dragstart);

    function dragstart(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        mousepos = e.screenX;
        $doc.on('mousemove.drag', drag); //в неймспейсе drag, чтобы потом отключить безболезненно для остальных листенеров
        $doc.one('mouseup', dragstop);
    }

    function drag(e) {
        clearTimeout(to);
        var delta = (e.screenX - mousepos) * ratio;
        to = setTimeout(function () { // таймаут чтобы события от мыши не перекрывали друг друга, 
            $doc.scrollLeft($doc.scrollLeft() + delta);
            mousepos = e.screenX;
        }, 1);
    }

    function dragstop() {
        $doc.off('mousemove.drag'); //отключаем свой mousemove.
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/z7JJg/

Comment: Спасибо большое за решение, ваше решение кроссбраузерно, единственно я бы поменял + на - в строке $doc.scrollLeft($doc.scrollLeft() + delta);, тогда именно эффект "тянуть" получается. Однако часто получается что страница немного дергается при прокрутке, не совсем гладкое решение, возможно это из-за самого jQuery.
Мне предложили еще такое решение http://jsfiddle.net/JaYLW/ все хорошо работает, но увы не работает в IE.

Comment: попробуйте убрать 1 в timeout,  у меня ничего не дергается.

Comment: мне вообще вот такое поведение больше нравится: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/z7JJg/5/

Comment: не, когда 0, то тоже тормозит, в примере нет, но в реальной странице, ничего не изменилось.  

to = setTimeout(function () { - вообще убрал, стало все плавно, и просто отлично. Главное кроссбраузерно, это вообще подарок ) Спасибо.